# loading xml from a file with php

Tags: php, xml

so in my sample php script I have

```
$get = file_get_contents('some-book/book.xml');
$arr = simplexml_load_string($get);?>
echo $arr->title;
echo "<br>";
echo $arr->year;
echo "<br>";
```

I get (as expected)

```
Some Book Title
2012
```

now the problem is when I try to load an xml in a foreach, the xml does not load.

```
$dir = ".";
$exclude = array( ".","..",".*","*.php" );
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), $exclude);
    foreach ($files as $file) : ?>

        <?php
          $filepath = str_replace(' ', '%20', $file);
          $get = file_get_contents( $filepath.'/'.$filepath.'.xml');
          $arr = simplexml_load_string($get);
          print_r($arr);
        ?>

        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
                <img src="<?= $filepath ?>/folder.jpg" alt="<?= $file ?>" class="img-responsive" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9">
                        <a href="<?= $file ?>">
                          <?php echo $arr->title; ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </li>

        <?php $arr = ''?>

    <?php endforeach;
}
```

this line is supposed to load the xml

```
$get = file_get_contents( $filepath.'/'.$filepath.'.xml');
```

and this line should echo the book title from the xml data

```
<?php echo $arr->title; ?>
```

Comment: Dont know about this line `<?php $arr = ''?>`. Should end with semicolon (;). So `<?php $arr = ''; ?>`
`

Comment: thanks, but did not fix the problem. Still not loading xml with path provided

Comment: @Yolo semicolon is optional since it is the last line !

Comment: @Timino i kind of thought so. But now i know.

Comment: check that your path for file `$filepath.'/'.$filepath.'.xml'`  is proper

Answer (score 0):

Both `file_get_contents` and `simplexml_load_string` will return boolean false on failure. I would recommend adding some defensive checks to find out what exactly is going wrong.

```
$get = file_get_contents( $filepath.'/'.$filepath.'.xml');
if ($get === false) {
  echo 'failed to read ' . $filepath . '/' . $filepath . '.xml <br>';
  var_dump(file_exists($filepath.'/'.$filepath.'.xml'));
  // if file_exists returns true, check the file permissions
  continue;
}

$arr = simplexml_load_string($get);
if ($arr === false) {
  echo 'check if ' . $filepath . ' contains valid xml <br>';
  continue;
}
```